# Azure devops build stuck in queue when using sonarqube

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

I’m using SonarQube 8.8 on Azure DevOps.
It’s work just fine, I have analyzed severals applications. However i have a problem on some applications:

When I run the pipeline it get's stuck in queue indefinitely "The agent request is not running because all potential agents are running other requests. Current position in queue:"

But as soon as I remove the sonarqube tasks, the build works just fine. There is no error message so I have no clue about where the problem may come from.

Can you please help

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67058794/sonarqube-qualitygate-status-is-pending-in-azure-pipelines/67060294#67060294

Answer (score 0):

In your current situation, we recommend you can check your agent pool and make sure your all agent is available. And please check your parallel jobs. Also, we recommend you can try to create more self-agent in your local machine and try to run this pipeline.

And you can refer Sourav's answer in the comment.

More details about this issue you can refer this doc: [You don't have enough concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#you-dont-have-enough-concurrency)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes across this; in our case we used Self Hosted agents. For the SonarQubePrepare to actually be able to start, the Java SDK must be installed on the agents. We therefore added an extra task to the pipeline:

```yaml
# Java is needed for the SonarQube analyzer tasks
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Install Java for SonarQube Analyzer'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '17' 
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'LocalDirectory'
    jdkFile: '<location of jdk zip file>'
    jdkDestinationDirectory: '$(agent.toolsDirectory)/jdk17'
```